# Relocating a Hard Drive with shared folders from Windows XP to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, sata, file-sharing

I have a secondary SATA HD in NTFS format that used to be a non-system HD for my Windows XP machine.  I have folders that were shared in the network.  The Windows XP has since gone out of commission, so I moved the HD as is to my Windows 7 64-bit machine.

I have no problem reading the files but I'm having problem sharing the folders.  If I look at "Sharing..." of the folder properties, it would list my user name, Everyone, and "unknown contact" which has the permission level of "owner".  I can't get rid of it.  I suppose these are the artifacts from the old Windows XP environment.

How do I clean the sharing up?  I think one way is to copy the content of the folder to a new folder and share from there, but I'd like to know if there's a better way.  For one thing, it's a huge folder and I don't have enough swap space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to sort it all out is to take ownership of all the files on the drive and overwrite the current security settings and remove all other accounts. Then set it up with the new permissions from your current computer.

In order to take over ownership:

- Right click on the folder and select the security tab.
- Click the Advanced button at the bottom of the screen.
- Select the Owner Tab and click the Edit button.
- Change the owner to your account.
- **Make sure you select the checkbox that reads: Replace owner on sub containers and objects**
- Hit Okay to apply all the changes. This step will take a while.
- After you have ownership, close all dialog windows and then restart the sharing process.

Comment: If that solved it for you I'd appreciate you marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I feel stupid but where do I do that?  BTW, even after changing the owner, when I try to modify a file (e.g. via Picasa to change caption of a JPG file), it would render the drive unresponsive.  Any idea?

Comment: There's a little check mark icon beside my answer. Picasa may be using different account credentials (such as System). Make sure that System also has permissions to all items as well.

Comment: Got it. I just dawned on me that the ownership on the Drive level was still under the old XP account!  I changed the ownership on the drive and so far (knock on wood) it seems a lot more stable! Thanks again!